# ImportError: cannot import name 'bigquery_storage_v1beta1' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm trying to use bigquery_storage to get data from google cloud big query according to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-storage-python-pandas#pip). However, after install all the modules (including the installation `pip install --upgrade 'google-cloud-bigquery[bqstorage,pandas]'`), I kept receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from google.cloud import bigquery_storage_v1beta1
ImportError: cannot import name 'bigquery_storage_v1beta1' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)
```

My import code:

```
import os
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import bigquery_storage_v1beta1
```

And both bigquery and storage are imported. bigquery storage is indeed installed according to `pip show google-cloud-bigquery-storage`:

```
Name: google-cloud-bigquery-storage
Version: 2.0.1
Summary: BigQuery Storage API API client library
Home-page: https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery-storage
Author: Google LLC
Author-email: googleapis-packages@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/phuong_anh_nguyen/coop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: libcst, google-api-core, proto-plus
Required-by:
```

I'm also in my venv and python version is 3.7. Does anybody know why this happens and how to solve it? I've been uninstalling, reinstalling and upgrading packages for a thousand times in different order and none has worked so far. I had this problem before and somehow it got resolved after maniacally installing packaes. I'm looking for a clear answer at last.

Answer (score 1):

I originally wanted to import `bigquery_storage_v1beta1` because that's how you download a table on bigquery to pandas dataframe according to GCP's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-storage-python-pandas#pip). What I found out was:

- As Sergey said, the library [is going to be deprecated soon](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/rpc/google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1beta1), new code should use [v1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/libraries#client-libraries-install-python)
- You don't need the library to download the data into a pandas dataframe: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/10083

Would still be nice to know why this happened tho

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `from google.cloud import bigquery_storage` instead? Google docs [recommend](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-storage-python-pandas#create_python_clients) it.

In order to use `bigquery_storage_v1beta1` you should `pip install google-cloud-bigquery-storage` [instead](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquerystorage/0.5.0/index.html#mac-linux). But it is [going to be deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/rpc/google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1beta1) soon.

Comment: I need bigquery_storage_v1beta1 to download into a pandas dataframe, and I also installed with pip install google-cloud-bigquery-storage already